# Getter on the instance of a javascript function itself to enable docstrings. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, string, class, overloading

**The utopic goal:**

```
str = "hello"
str.doc = "this is a string"
console.log(str) //prints 'hello'
console.log(str.doc) //should prints the docstring
```

However, strings are immutable and this above is not possible.

**How I tried to workaround:**

```
str = new String("hello")
str.doc = "this is a string"
console.log(str) //prints the string object but not 'hello'
console.log(""+str) //prints "hello"
console.log(str.doc) //correctly prints the docstring
```

As you can see, only when .valueOf() or .toString() is called, you get the raw string. The goal is to get the string when it's directly called.

Another tempt of workaround (in coffescript, for shortness: 3 lines vs ~15)

```
class Configuration
    constructor: (@value, @doc) ->
    @::valueOf = -> @value
```

This is pretty similar to `new String()`. It just prototypes the `valueOf()` method on the object. The problem is the same as above. You cannot directly `console.log(str)` to prints the raw string and both use `console.log(str.doc)`

**The question:**

Is it possible in some way to achieve this, without have to refactor my whole codebase ?

Comment: This is a very interesting question. What's the use case?

Comment: For the configuration of my angular app. I store the public environment variables (like the rest backend url) in a env-specific file, defining them in a singleton, than I can later use everywhere

Comment: Can you share an example of how are you using these strings? Since for all practical purpose `new String()` should solve your problem.

Comment: E.g. in a singleton: `API = {login: $resource(__env.dbURL + "auth/login")}` In this case `new String()` will work, due to the concatenation but not here: `user.picture = __env.userDefaultImage` since there is no concatenation, this would return the string object instead of the actual raw string, if I use `new String()`. Probably I will go for a bit of refactoring replacing with env.image + "", not really clean but seems to be the only workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, I'll go for a bit of refactoring replacing the variables like `str` with `str + ""` and so using `new String()`, not really clean but seems to be the only quick workaround. In fact, the optimal solution would be to simply use a singleton like the following:

```
config = {
    mySetting: {
        value: "settingValue",
        docstring: "my doc string"
    }
}
```

And where necessary use it with: `config.mySetting.value`
But that would be to do a lot of refactoring of a complex app, not a priority for now. Thank you all for your responses!

Answer (score 2):

You can prototype String. See [fiddle](https://jsbin.com/jomoji/edit?js,console)

```
// String.prototype.__defineGetter__("doc", function() { return "test" }); //deprecated

Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "doc", {
  get: function doc() {
    return "this is a string";
  }
});
console.log("this is a string".doc);
```

Comment: the non-deprecated way is supported in ES5 browsers

Comment: Your solution actually works :D but prototyping all the strings is not exactly clean and generally I avoid at all to 'dirty' native objects

Answer (score 0):

I don't condone this, but you could override `console.log`, so that it calls valueOf on any String arguments:

```
var oldConsoleLog = console.log;
console.log = function ( ) {
    oldConsoleLog.apply( console, [].map.call( arguments, function ( arg ) { return arg instanceof String ? arg.valueOf() : arg; } ) );
};
```